# autoload bitbucket repository + composer.json

Tags: php, json, git, composer-php

I want to add a bitbucket repository to my vendor folder using composer. This is what I have in my composer.json:

```
{
    "require": {
        "silex/silex": "~1.1",
        "doctrine/dbal": "2.2.*",
        "twig/twig" : "1.*",
        "symfony/twig-bridge": "~2.3",
        "twitter/bootstrap": "*",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "leafo/lessphp": "*",
        "silex/web-profiler": "~1.0",
        "symfony/security": "~2.3",
        "symfony/form": "~2.3",
        "symfony/validator": "~2.3",
        "symfony/config": "~2.3",
        "symfony/translation": "~2.3",
        "monolog/monolog": ">=1.0.0",
        "symfony/yaml": "~2.3",
        "jasongrimes": "dev-master"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "jasongrimes",
                "version": "dev-master",
                "source": {
                    "url": "mybitbucketurl",
                    "type": "git",
                    "reference": "origin/master"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I don't have a composer.json in my bitbucket repository that I want to add through composer. Now when I run my application I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'SimpleUser\UserServiceProvider' not found in app/bootstrap.php on line 82
```

How can I make sure this is also in the autoloader?

Comment: Shouldn't it be only `master` inside `reference`? Apart from that it's almost identical to what I use to clone a GitHub repository into my vendors.

Comment: your error doesn't relate to composer or bitbucket, PHP just cannot load the class

Comment: Where is the SimpleUser\UserServiceProvider coming from? are you trying to PSR-0 autoload it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When you specify a package repository, you are basically providing all of the details that would be in that package's composer.json if it had one. For autoloading to work, an `autoload` property for the package must be specified. The composer manual has [details on the `autoload` property](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload).

If your bitbucket repository conforms to PSR-0 or PSR-4, you simply need to specify the correct standard, and where the classes to be loaded are stored in the repository. For example, with PSR-4 and your classes stored in the `src/` directory:

```
{
    "require": {
        "jasongrimes": "dev-master"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "jasongrimes",
                "version": "dev-master",
                "source": {
                    "url": "mybitbucketurl",
                    "type": "git",
                    "reference": "origin/master"
                },
                "autoload": {
                    "psr-4": { "": "src/" }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Otherwise, you can use `classmap` to specify directories or files to be scanned for `.php` or `.inc` files with classes. For example, if the class you are attempting to load is located in the file `SimpleUser/UserServiceProvider.php` in your repository:

```
{
    "require": {
        "jasongrimes": "dev-master"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "jasongrimes",
                "version": "dev-master",
                "source": {
                    "url": "mybitbucketurl",
                    "type": "git",
                    "reference": "origin/master"
                },
                "autoload": {
                    "classmap": [ "SimpleUser/UserServiceProvider.php" ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```