# How do I use a Laravel package created by me in production?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, packagist

I'm writing an app using Laravel 4.2. This time, I needed some extra functionality and I decided to create a package. I used the `workbench` functionality as described [in Laravel's docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/packages).

Currently (and locally), the package is very small but it suits my app very well. I don't think this should be published to the community because it is still very green. I'll put a few hours into it when I finish with my app but I can't right now.

Now, I know the `workbench/` directory is not to be pushed to production. Then, how do I use my package on production?

So far, I heard I have to push the package to GitHub (which I already did), and then publish it on Packagist. But I feel that publishing the script as is won't be helpful to others and might as well harm those in search of this functionality (like me a few days ago) on this so under developed package.

Is there a way to add my package to my app's `composer.json` and have it installed without publishing it to the community while it's under development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is "private repository". Inside your composer.json file you can define an object `repositories` where you can define other locations to search for this repository

Detailed explanation can be found on [Autoload bitbucket repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23139496/autoload-bitbucket-repository-composer-json). The same principal is true for github.